# Why are my update queries with comparable matching rows and similar filters much faster the 2nd time?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-5.7

We had to run a couple of update queries directly on a prod mysql datastore. Mysql 5.7 is being used.

The first of them was something like below:

```
Update dbName.tableName 
set row1 = 1 
where clientID = 123 and
identifier like 'ABC.%'
limit 16000
```

The above query matched around 16k rows and took 29 seconds to run.

My second query was something like

```
Update dbName.tableName
set row1 = 1 ,
row2 = 2
where clientId = 123 and
identifier like 'XYZ.%'
limit 8000
```

This query took only 1.2 seconds to run and matched around 8000 rows.

There is no index on any of the filters or any of the columns that are being modified.

I checked mysql's performance monitor and there was nothing anomalous happening throughout the duration of both of these queries.

I don't think mysql query cache is involved as I am given to understand that it works only on select queries whose statements are the same when compared "byte for byte".

How is the second query so much faster than the first when the matching rows are comparable and the filters are similar?

Comment: Notwithstanding your comments above, the answer is still cache.

Comment: Run the first query twice, or reverse the order. You'll find the second query to be run is usually faster than the first (if you haven't run a query for a while).

Answer (score 0):

A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` is asking for random rows; beware.

Add this composite `INDEX(clientId, identifier)`.

The timing anomaly *may* be explained by this:

The first query did not find any of the table in cache (the "buffer pool"), so it read it all from disk.  Since there was no useful index, it had to read *all*.  The second query found the entire table cached, so it was much faster.  Meanwhile, I will guess that the disk is SSD, not HDD.

A single update modifying 16K rows smells like a poor schema design.  Would you like to discuss that further?

The "Query cache" is useful only for `SELECTs`.  The QC is purged by write operations, so it will not explain the difference.  It is different than the "buffer pool".  (The QC may even be turned off.)